# How can I write and run a SEDE query without the query itself being visible to other regular SEDE users?

Tags: support, data-explorer

How can I write and run a query in SEDE without the query itself being visible to other regular SEDE users, such as in the "everything" tab of the "queries" page?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Data Explorer "parameters" aren't parameters at all. They are plain string replace operations.

So all you need is [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1825617?query=select+top+10+*+from+posts) so you can provide the actual statement as parameter:

```
##query##
```

And this is how you use it:

[image: sql editor with parameter query and run query button]

Note that you can't and shouldn't add any of the optional type declarations. For example `##query:string##` won't work because now the value you provide will be enclosed in single quotes. So given

> select * from posts

will become

> 'select * from posts'

and that won't run.

Keep in mind SEDE is updated once a week on Sunday.
Never forget that [Monica Cellio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/162102/monica-cellio) created the awesome [SEDE Tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial).
Say "Hi" in [SEDE chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/data-explorer-sede).

Answer (score 8):

Not sure if I'm missing anything, but at the very least, the following technique won't give away the query of interest in the "everything" tab of the queries listing:

```sql
DECLARE @query nvarchar(max) = ##query:string##;
EXEC sp_executesql @stmt=@query;
```

The "everything" tab of the queries listing (*to my knowledge*) doesn't show what arguments were passed to parameters, so the above, which is just a wrapper query that runs a query passed as an argument to the parameter named "`query`", will simply show up in the "everything" tab as:

> ```sql
> DECLARE @query nvarchar(max) = ##query:string##;
> EXEC sp_executesql @stmt=@query;
> ```

I wanted to name the parameter `sql` instead of `query`, but [that was being weird](/q/398479/997587).

This won't be hidden to SE staff. They have a record of queries that are run, and also a since-last-refresh query cache which is used for performance. Interestingly, that cache includes parameter arguments, so using this technique won't bust that query cache and you can still enjoy its benefits.

#### Using parameters

If your query takes parameters, you can still handle this with a bit of extra stuff.

For example, let's say your query is:

```sql
SELECT arg1 = ##param1:string##, arg2 = ##param2:int##, arg3 = ##param3:float##;
```

Then you'd need to modify your query to something like:

```sql
SELECT arg1 = @param1, arg2 = @param2, arg3 = @param3;
```

And modify the the wrapper to something like:

```sql
DECLARE
  @query nvarchar(max) = ##query:string##,
  @arg1 nvarchar(max)  = ##param1:string##,
  @arg2 int            = ##param2:int##,
  @arg3 float          = ##param3:float##
  ;
EXEC sp_executesql @stmt=@query,
  @params=N'@param1 nvarchar(max),@param2 int,@param3 float',
  @param1=@arg1,@param2=@arg2,@param3=@arg3;
```

Docs for `sp_executesql` are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql).